# Spartacus deployment first time in CCV2 gets stuck and after 13-14 hours it then fails

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

We are currently trying to deploy our Spartacus application in one of the cloud environment. The build is successful but deployment is getting stuck at "Starting Js Storefront" and after 13-14 hours it then fails.

Answer (score 0):

Contact SAP Support for your subscription, so that they can investigate. In most cases you, can't do anything about it and SAP will need to resolve it. It may be due to issues in SAP infrastructure. This is based on personal experience.

Comment: @Nimantha We encountered this issue before and the only way to fix this was for SAP to check the issue. SAP Commerce in Public Cloud is Platform-as-a-Service. There are certain things out of your control and only SAP can check.